# How to integrate this control in my App in Eclipse.?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-layout, android-widget

i was looking for Scrollable Tab for my application, but i m stuck here.

i found a [website](http://viewpagerindicator.com) that gives this control. But i don't know how to integrate this in eclipse.?

If anybody had used this with eclipse, please guyz share with me. i need to implement in my application.

Directory Structure for the file that i had downloaded:

```
library
   -> libs
   ->    -> android-support-v4.jar
   -> res
   -> src
   -> AndroidManifest.xml
   -> pom.xml
Sample
   -> libs
   ->    -> android-support-v4.jar
   -> psd
   -> res
   -> src
   -> AndroidManifest.xml
   -> logo.png
   -> pom.xml
.gitignore
checkstyle.xml
pom.xml
```

Comment: Import Sample as Android application in eclipse

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
Right click your project, select 'Android tools' -> 'Add support library'